# Java Error running .jar, but nothing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, runtime-error

When I try to run my newly finished program from my desktop as a .jar file it gets stuck while running on the "Please Wait..." screen I have to indicate my program is still loading. At the same time, running it from Eclipse IDE it works perfectly fine! Running

```
java -jar C:\path\to\my\jar\file.jar
```

results in an `Error` that looks like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ...
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)...
```

*Yes*, I know [`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dclp2/index.html) means there was an `Exception` while loading some static variable in a class. The error was a `NullPointerException` in an `ImageIcon`, meaning one of my (many) static `ImageIcon`'s was given a null URL to load. I used `getClass().getResource("someFile")` which returns null if nothing was found. **Yes, I have spelled all the image names correctly**. Here is my code:

```
public static final ImageIcon cloud = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("cloud.png"));
public static final ImageIcon whiteFlower = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("white_flower.png"));
public static final ImageIcon pinkFlower = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("pink_flower.png"));
public static final ImageIcon redFlower = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("red_flower.png"));
public static final ImageIcon blueFlower = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("blue_flower.png"));
public static final ImageIcon bird1 = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\bird1.png"));
public static final ImageIcon bird2 = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\bird2.png"));
public static final ImageIcon bird3 = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\bird3.png"));
public static final ImageIcon bird4 = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\bird4.png"));
public static final ImageIcon bird5 = bird4;
public static final ImageIcon bird6 = bird3;
public static final ImageIcon bird7 = bird2;
public static final ImageIcon bird8 = bird1;
public static final ImageIcon moon = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("moon.png"));
public static final ScaledImageIcon star = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("star.png"), 0.225/*average of 0.15 and 0.3*/);
public static final PixelResizeImageIcon squirrel = new PixelResizeImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("squirrel.gif"/*"bunny.gif"*/), 1.5);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird1 = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\white1.png"), 1);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird2 = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\white2.png"), 1);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird3 = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\white3.png"), 1);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird4 = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\white4.png"), 1);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird5 = new ScaledImageIcon(SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation\\white5.png"), 1);
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird6 = whiteBird4;
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird7 = whiteBird3;
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird8 = whiteBird2;
public static final ScaledImageIcon whiteBird9 = whiteBird1;
```

And here is my project:

[image: Birthday Card Project Image]

Everything is working *perfectly fine* in Eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar file and run it with `java -jar` it gives me an error! Can somebody help ***please***?

Comment: I assume that this affects all images and not just one? Sounds like a classpath problem.. In Eclipse everything is set to go, and when you export it into a jar, something goes astray. And just to avoid this one: Did you check the content of the jar? Is everything where it should be?

Comment: @U-No-Poo I just decompiled the .jar in JD-GUI, everything seems to be where it should be, I'm going to check the classpath again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that all the images are in the jar, and use forward slashes rather than backslashes for resource paths:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("bird_animation/white1.png")
```

Comment: **Thank you**! The problem _was_ the forward slashes. I wonder why Eclipse thinks its OK, but plain Java doesn't? Anyway, it solved the problem :)

Comment: Hi, I have a different scenario with regards to output. Both ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt) and Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) giving me SUCCESS when run in Eclipse. But both of them returning NULL when run from a executable jar on windows machine. Is there something I'm missing here?